# Laradock and OpenSSL: dh key too small

Tags: laravel, nginx, openssl, diffie-hellman, laradock

I have a project made with Laradock. If I try to send an email with Laravel, it returns this error:

> Connection could not be established with host out.postassl.it
> :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
> Error messages: error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key
> too small

Outstide the docker, it works, so I think the problem is in some docker container.
This is the nginx.conf:

```
...
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparam.pem #4096
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  'HIGH:!kRSA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-$
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
...
```

default.conf:

```
...
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
...
}
...
```

How I can solve the error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem in development aswell.

You can solve the problem by lowering the TLS security settings in the `php-fpm` service

1. `docker-compose exec php-fpm bash`
2. root@8d1d14a86c67:/var/www# `apt-get update && apt-get install vim -y`
3. `vi /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`
4. Change `TLSv1.2` to `TLSv1` and `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` to `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`
5. Save file with `CTRL + ZZ`
6. restart php-fpm `docker-compose restart php-fpm`

Comment: Thanks. See also this commit: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/pull/2698